# What is `.git`'s search path for binary scripts and how do I configure it?

Tags: bash, git, githooks

Git has a unique feature: custom git extensions can be added so long as they are executable scripts on the PATH with the appropriate name scheme:

```
# ~/bin/git-foo
#! /bin/bash
echo foo
```

```
$: git foo
foo
```

This is great for some kind of power user with a large amount of knowledge in the use of git, willing to maintain personal scripts and a PATH variable.

However, it would be great to be able to have a project with custom git extensions that works out-of-the-box after a clone.

```
$ git clone .../git-extensions.git

$ cd git-extensions
$ git foo
foo
```

In order to do that for personal use, I've been creating `sourceme` files that do various things:

```
$ git clone .../git-extensions
$ cd git-extensions
$ source sourceme && git foo
foo
```

However, that is for personal use.  I'd like to avoid that if possible. In order to do that, my current idea is to figure out what `git`'s local search path is for executable functions and place my `git-extensions` in that location, similar to the way `.git/hooks` work.

So my question amounts to: what is `git`'s local search path for executables, or how do I configure it?

And the greater objective is: how do I set up git extensions locally without causing the user of a fresh clone to do something extra like source some shell file in order to access the extensions in the git workflow?

---

Few caveats, as I suppose there is limited understanding w.r.t. git and "executables".

In the linux space, executables generally refer to scripts.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
echo foo
```

If I install such a script in my path with the name `git-foo`:

```
$ mkdir ~/cmds
$ cp foo.sh ~/cmds/git-foo
$ chmod +x ~/cmds/git-foo
$ export PATH="~/cmds:${PATH}"
$ git foo
foo
```

Will now be possible. In convention with most linux tools, git ought to have some PATH variable I can configure globally that allows GIT and GIT ONLY to have ~/cmds/ on the PATH it uses to resolve normal git extensions.

This configuration, in accordance with GIT, also ought to be configurable locally in a project s.t. I can include my `cmds` folder in my git repo for a consistent git experience upon cloning rather than upon cloning, reading a readme, and setting up a PATH.

What is that configurable parameter?

^^^ this is my question, explicitly.

Comment: Think about the security impact here. If `clone`ing a repo installed code to be run without explicit user intent, people would have to be a lot more careful about what projects they checked out. That's why cloning a repo doesn't create hooks, and also why any proposal to have an automatic/default search path including directories that _can_ be included in a checkout -- as this question asks for -- would certainly be rejected.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so what you are saying is that for my use case, the `sourceme` file (or something like that) would be the go to approach.  Consider this in terms of my use case, which I'll share: avoiding the cloud costs of `git-lfs` using a data version control system in a user agnostic fashion (grafted into git commands with hooks and extensions). Obviously, security is ultimately trumped by costs of use -- which is the prime factor that forms security concepts and objectives.

Comment: It's not obvious at all to me that security is "trumped" by cost-of-use; security risk can best be modeled by a Poisson distribution for low-frequency high-impact events. If the cost of an event when it occurs is high enough, it can become worth mitigating even if the chance of it happening in any given moment is low -- that's why we mitigate against earthquakes, car accidents, and any other kind of discrete-event loss; how serious that risk is can be proxied by cost to insure against it, and cyber insurance is expensive indeed these days.

Comment: And yes, I agree that something like `sourceme` is appropriate.

Comment: ...in the case of an ubiquitous tool like git, the attack surface is broad, making secure defaults all the more important. _You_ might use git only to check out codebases built by your coworkers, and be willing to consider a `git clone` equivalent to arbitrary code execution -- but that's nothing even remotely near the full set of use cases or risk profiles.

Comment: BTW, if you _do_ want `cd`ing into a given directory to do automatic shell configuration, you might look at [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/) for a tool with a well-thought-through design for the purpose (including ensuring that the end user has control over which trees are trusted to exert such control).

Comment: Fair 'nuff. That said, I stand by the scare quotes, which were included to indicate that I didn't (and still don't) understand the exact parameters around which cost-of-use is claimed to have general supremacy over security. (If you were including the costs incurred by a lack of security, I don't see how one side can be generally supreme over the other, as opposed needing to incorporate case-by-case details -- as determined, on the security end, by threat modeling -- into the analysis).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy then we are talking about content -- in which case I'd argue that costs are the most general concept. Security, as a concept, is mitigation of costs. So this is an axiom in the semantics and definition of terms: security is subordinate to cost, and cost defines security.

Comment: I agree as to truth of the statement, then, but also find it to be vacuous: Weighing the balance depends on case-by-case analysis of the utility gained by an expedient path against the security costs of offering that path, whether or not the result is expressed as a cost function; looking through the lens makes no difference in terms of what needs to be considered to come to a conclusion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sounds like there is a pareto frontier of security and utility.  There is a price point for git large file storage services that, when free, makes you correct...and when high, makes workarounds necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to force your binary to be in Git's search path after a clone, or in any event, to execute any command directly after a clone without user intervention.  If that were possible, it would be a serious security vulnerability allowing arbitrary code execution.

In the standard Linux distribution model, the special path location where Git looks for internal binaries is specified internally as `GIT_EXEC_PATH` in the environment.  However, this is usually a system path like `/usr/lib/git-core/` and is typically only writable by `root`.

Git does look in `PATH` for programs, but setting that requires either sourcing a file or altering the user's shell configuration, which requires executing some code.  I will also assure you that I am not the only person who gets extremely cranky when people or programs attempt to modify my `PATH` settings, so attempting to do so without user knowledge and consent (e.g., by hiding it in a Makefile) is not advised, nor is installing hooks without the user's and consent.  If you're changing the way the user's system works or installing software, you should be extremely transparent about that fact to the user and document it clearly.

You can, of course, provide a repository of Git extensions and a script to install them in a place which might be in the user's `PATH`, such as `~/.local/bin`.  If you honestly and accurately report that fact to the user, then they might install your extensions, much like people install a variety of other extensions, such as `git-imerge` or `git-autofixup`, and your goal would be achieved.

Comment: BTW, I did mention `direnv` in comments on the question; this tool can (with a user's per-directory consent) amend `PATH` or other environment variables when entering a directory subtree and undo those changes when leaving that tree.

Comment: Sure, and that fits into my category of “altering the user's shell configuration”.  However, unless the repository is highly trusted, it's not secure to allow the code to change (e.g., by pulling) unless the user is prompted again, so it's hard to use effectively in a secure way.

Comment: _nod_; I'd only advise its use when a repository contains code one is otherwise running unsandboxed / with the same privilege level. (Running `make` without reviewing everything it invokes is arbitrary code execution itself, after all).

Comment: When you clone a git project, you may include scripts in  script folder. If you change to the project directory, you may call the scripts via `./scripts/foo.sh`.  If you name the script `scripts/git-foo`, then you may call the scripts via `git foo`, so long as git looks for the scripts in that path. This *should* be configurable local to the git project.  How on earth is the ability to configure git to behave the way you would like local to your own project a security vulnerability? Frankly, `direnv` is a fine workaround. But the pedantic posturing on a question in earnest is alarming.